# Making a data frame, and using it to create a histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Use base R to obtain a data frame with only those observations where there was more than 0.1 mm of rain.

*Answer:*

```
Raintimes = c(filter(weather, weather$RAIN > 0.1))
```

and the next question:

Produce a histogram of the wind direction when there was more than 0.1 mm of rain.  Does there appear to be a prominent direction of wind when it is raining?

*Answer:*

```
 ggplot(data = Raintimes, aes_string( x= "WINDIR", group=1)) + geom_histogram(color = "black", fill = "white", bins = 8)
```

These are what I have tried, i'm new to using r.  I get this error: 
Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a numeric vector

I don't know what to do, any advice?

Comment: Try `Raintimes <- subset(weather, RAIN>0.1)` and check with `str(Raintimes)` that it is indeed a `data.frame` with more than zero rows.

Comment: yes, by using `c`, your changing the underlying structure of dataframe. Do `Raintimes <- filter(weather, RAIN > 0.1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can get you started, given `WINDIR` is the variable you want to plot.

```r
weather %>%
  filter(RAIN > 0.1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(WINDIR)) + geom_histogram(color = "black", fill = "white", bins=8)
```

Comment: thank you, and to the rest of the comments.  I'm getting the hang of this thanks you all of you